# Declaring a super class in a TypeScript definition file

Tags: typescript, abstract-class

I'm trying to create a super class in TypeScript which will serve as a template for other classes in various other files. Because I want to reuse the class in multiple projects I want to declare it in a definition file.

Here are the three files I have currently:

1. app.ts

   ```javascript
   /// <reference path="genericStuff.d.ts" />

   module Foo.Sub {
       export class MyClass extends SomeSuperClass {
           constructor(input: string) {
               super();
               console.log(input);
           }

           someTemplateMethod = () => { console.log("working..."); }
       }
   }
   ```
2. genericStuff.ts

   ```javascript
   /// <reference path="genericStuff.d.ts" />

   module Foo {
       export class SomeSuperClass {
           constructor() {
               console.log("Super constructor");
           }

           someTemplateMethod = () => { /* no op */ }
           anotherTemplateMethod = () => { /* no op */ }
       }

       export class SomeOtherClass implements IDoSomething {
           doSomething() { }
       }
   }
   ```
3. genericStuff.d.ts

   ```javascript
   declare module Foo {
       interface IDoSomething {
           doSomething: () => void;
       }

       export class SomeSuperClass {
           someTemplateMethod: () => void;
           anotherTemplateMethod: () => void;
       }
   }
   ```

This presents me with an error:

> error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'SomeSuperClass'.

This makes perfect sense, but isn't helpful.

**I don't want to reference `genericStuff.ts` directly from `app.ts`**, but I do want to extend a class from that file. Is this possible?

Comment: Abstract classes are coming in TypeScript 1.6. I don't understand why `SomeAbstractClass` is also defined in `genericStuff.d.ts`. Why not use a typescript file in multiple projects instead of a definition file?

Comment: Oh, shoot, I called this "Abstract" even though it may not technically be abstract. I could reword it so the post is merely about `extend`ing classes.

Comment: @DavidSherret Concerning your question, there was an issue with referencing a single `.ts` file from multiple projects in a Visual Studio solution, where the build of each project would start calling `tsc`. I'm trying to look for the associated SO answer that suggested using a `d.ts` file to solve this, but I did this a while back already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the following files :

```
module Foo {

    export interface IDoSomething {
        doSomething: () => void;
    }

    export class SomeSuperClass {
        constructor() {
            console.log("Super constructor");
        }

        someTemplateMethod = () => { /* no op */ }
        anotherTemplateMethod = () => { /* no op */ }
    }

    export class SomeOtherClass implements IDoSomething {
        doSomething() { }
    }
}
```

Compile with `-d` to let typescript create the `.d.ts` file, which will look like :

```
declare module Foo {
    interface IDoSomething {
        doSomething: () => void;
    }

    export class SomeSuperClass {
        someTemplateMethod: () => void;
        anotherTemplateMethod: () => void;
    }
    export class SomeOtherClass implements IDoSomething {
        doSomething():void;
    }
}
```

Which you can then use from `app.ts`

Comment: This answer is similar to [@mallison's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32074584/419956), with the exception of duplicating `IDoSomething` in the `genericStuff.ts` and `.d.ts` files instead of moving it to its own file, right?

Comment: Also the `.d.ts` is *generated* by the compiler. You don't need to write it yourself

Comment: Ah yes, that's a neat trick I didn't know of yet, thx! Not sure if that will help in my actual scenario, but certainly useful for the question as posed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the reference to `genericStuff.d.ts` in your `genericStuff.ts` file. From TypeScript's perspective your defining the same class twice.

Comment: But then `IDoSomething` can't be found anymore, causing an error for `tsc genericStuff.ts`.

Comment: `IDoSomething` should be moved into it's own file and referenced separately.  Or you could move it into `genericStuff.ts` and have TypeScript generate the definition file for you by doing `tsc -d genericStuff.ts`